# When does CSS get resolved/evaluated?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list of divs, each with a 'createdDate' attribute, I evaluate each div's createdDate, 
I add another attribute 'isNew' , if it is less than 7 days old set true, false otherwise.

The css has:

```
div[isNew=true] div.title{ background:red }
```

intending to set the background red when is less than 7 days.

using firebug and ie Dev tools - shows the background as set red, by the matching rule.

The browser is not displaying the title div in red though.

is there a way to nudge the css evaluation to redraw? or a better way?

Comment: A better way? Why not create CSS classes for each specific rule and using your server side language of choice append the respective class to the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this snippet http://jsfiddle.net/fcalderan/Gh7Ud/ works as expected I would suggest to check markup and remaining css rules, probably you redefine after that style somewhere

Note: your code requires an attribute '`isNew`': if you are in control of html code, it's better if you make it future-proof changing it as '`data-isNew`'

As suggested by Zlatev, creating a class 'ad hoc' it's another solution and this will ensure crossbrowsing, because oldest browser doesn't recognize the CSS attribute selector. BTW I only suggest to not use a `.red` class because it would be too much bound to the element style (what if you change the colour?), so it's better preferring a semantic class, like `.newtitle`

Comment: cool tool ( jsfiddle ) not seen that one before. I've tweaked you sample,a bit so the behaviour follows what I was trying to do. if you run it now, the title does not turn red. Yet inspect says its red!

Comment: Adrian your code works as expected (I'm using FF3.6.12) but it works only using that line of javascript. the title is black with a background red as you specified.

Comment: Not in IE7, IE8 or Chrome 9... looks like changes to an elements attributes might not get evaluated by  its children in those browsers

Comment: I suggest to make a real check on real browser without jsfiddle. Just a simple html document with the necessary markup and style.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new rule:

```
.red { background: red; } // to be safe and sure, you can make it important
```

Apply it via jQuery when needed by `.addClass()` or form the backend

Comment: yeah i'm converting it to do this instead. I was intending to keep the css and code separate

Comment: Except don't use `red` as the class name, what happens when you want to change it to blue?